# Installation Issue compizconfig-settings-manager

Tags: package-management, python, compiz

HOW to install **compizconfig-settings-manager**.  I tried to install from ubuntu store but it show unable to install. I also tried on terminal but it throw error.
I have **UBUNTU 22.10.**

This is terminal error I get:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-gi-cairo : Depends: python3-gi (= 3.42.1-1) but 3.42.2-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**please provide detail solution, because I am very new to command line.**
I also tried this command: sudo apt-get install python3-gi
but it says--->            python3-gi is already the newest version (3.42.2-2).

Comment: Looking at the details in your question it wants an older version of one of the files. Depends: python3-gi (= 3.42.1-1) you have already the newest version (3.42.2-2).

Comment: I thought they axed ccsm already :/

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1438353/edit) to include the complete output of `apt policy compizconfig-settings-manager`. Copy and paste the complete output into your question above.